# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' /Dijkstra's algorithm to finding the shortest path of a weighted graph

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm trying to make a dijkstra algorithm solution to a finding the shortest path problem. I made use of an adjacency list but i still get this error: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

This is the code i made:

```
def dij(graph, start,goal):
    shortest_distance = {}
    track_predecessor = {}
    unseenNodes = graph
    infinity = 999999
    track_path = []

    for node in unseenNodes:
        shortest_distance[node] = infinity
    shortest_distance[start] = 0

    while unseenNodes:
        min_distance_node = None

        for node in unseenNodes:
            if min_distance_node is None:
                min_distance_node = node
            elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[min_distance_node]:
                min_distance_node = node

        path_options = graph[min_distance_node].items()

        for (child_node, weight) in path_options:
            if weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node] < shortest_distance[child_node]:
                shortest_distance[child_node] = weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node]
                track_predecessor[child_node] = min_distance_node

        unseenNodes.pop(min_distance_node)
    currentNode = goal

    while currentNode != start:
       try:
           track_path.insert(0, currentNode)
           currentNode = track_predecessor[currentNode]

       except KeyError:
           print("path does not exist")
           break

    track_path.insert(0, start)

    if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
        print("Shortest distance is" + str(shortest_distance[goal]))
        print("Optimal path is" + str(track_path))

dij(graph,"Acton Town","Aldgate")
```

I was expecting the most optimal route to get from Acton Town to Aldgate. How do i fix the issue?

Comment: I suspect there is something awry with your 'graph' object.
This is a common problem when working with dynamic languages.
Here are some links that may help you validate your input 'graph'.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Comment: thanks for the help. I just made use of the data from the spreadsheet and turned it into an adjacency matrix rather than doing it manually. I also used networkx library to find the shortest distance